# Send email with dynamic content for the list of users from database

Tags: php, mysql, api, email

I have list of users to whom I have to send an email with separate link for each user.

My email - 
Dear user,

Some message content here. To confirm your action click here.

The list of users is save in my database in the below format -

Sr. No - User Email - Link

I have tried the below code, the page goes in loop of loading and nothing happens. I am trying to use an email API here, but I am open to other ideas through which I can accomplish my goal.

```
    ob_start ();
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        include_once("connect.php");
        $sql1 = "SELECT email FROM `tablename`";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $recipients = $row["email"];
                $url = $row["url"];
                try {
                    require_once 'SarvMTA_PHP/Sarv.php';
                    $sarv = new Sarv('userid', 'apitoken',
                        'SarvTES_APP_DOMAIN');
                    $smtp_user_name = "smtpusername";
                    $message["html"] = "
Please follow this link to confirm: .<a href='{$url}'>Click here </a>";
                    $message["subject"] = " subject";
                    $message["from_email"] = "TR <emai@mysite.com>";
                    $message["to"] = array(
                        array("email" => $recipient['email'], "name" => $recipient['name'], "type" => "to")
                    );
                    $message["headers"] = array("Reply-To" => "senderemail@mysite.com", "X-
Unique-Id" => "Id");
                    $result = $sarv->messages->sendMail($smtp_user_name, $message);
                    print_r($result);
                } catch (Sarv_Error $e) {
// Sarv errors are thrown as exceptions
                    echo "A sarv error occurred: " . get_class($e) . " - " . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }  else {
                echo "All mails sent ! Well done";
            }
```

Comment: First of all correct your message to look like this "Please follow this link to confirm: .<a href='{$url}'>Click here </a>"; Next where is the $url variable defined? also correct your code a bit, you dont need to require_once and create object inside loop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to get rid of all the blank lines in your code. They are pointless and make your code harder to read. Please also give more details about what goes wrong.

Comment: did the changes. Now the page is throwing http 500 error

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of issues in your code.

> Where is this used? $recipients = $row["email"];

and

> where is the $recipient variable defined? $recipient['email'] and $recipient['name']

If we assume **$recipient = $row**, clearly you are missing **name** in your **SQL select statement**

Correct your **SQL statement** to look like this (assuming **name column** exists in the table)

```
select name,email,url from `tablename`
```

Next replace

```
$recipient = $row;
//instead of
$recipients = $row['email'];
```

Then correct your message

```
$message["html"] = "Please follow this link to confirm: .<a href='{$url}'>Click here </a>";
```

Also, move these two lines outside the loop (may be after the **if statement**)

```
require_once 'SarvMTA_PHP/Sarv.php';
$sarv = new Sarv('userid', 'apitoken', 'SarvTES_APP_DOMAIN');
```

Comment: To add... There is also an "else" hanging off the "while" loop instead of the if statement. But that message can just be put after the while is completed without the need for the else...